# How to send encrypted mail using mailx command in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, email, unix, shell, pgp

I want to make my email encrypted as email is confidential. Can anyone please tell me how to encrypt the email using the mailx command. In my shell script I have already used mailx to send the emails, so I want this to be done by mailx command only. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use PGP on the commandline: http://www.symantec.com/command-line

Comment: Encrypt *how*...?

Comment: can you please provide me the format for that? whether should I use pgp or gpg ?

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how I did it:

1. Create text file.
2. Encrypt that text file.
3. Attach that encrypted text file to an email.

Here is a Bash script that implements the idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
date > /tmp/gpgtxt.txt


gpg -ea -r receiver@mail.com /tmp/gpgtxt.txt

cat /tmp/gpgtxt.txt.asc | mailx -s "cli encryption" \
-a /tmp/gpgtxt.txt.asc \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 \
-S from="sender@send.com" \
-S smtp-auth-user=sender@send.com \
-S smtp-auth-password="senderpassword" \
receiver@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
cat "your message" > msg # just type your message. You can use editor too. 
gpg -ear "reciever gpg key" msg # encrypt it.
cat msg.asc | mail -s "subject" "reciever mail address" # Hit enter.
```

Comment: `cat` takes a files as an argument, not a string. So unless you have a file called `your\ message`, this will give you a "No such file or directory" error...